# HttpUtil.encodeUrl not appending jsessionid when cookies are disabled?

Tags: java, liferay, velocity

I'm developing a liferay theme on which I have to place some links to other pages. Now I wanted to put those links like `${httpUtil.encodeUrl("\myPage"")}.` However when I disable cookies and visit the page I still see the page without the jsessionid appended to the myPage url. Does anyone know why this happens and a possible sollution?

I also tried some velocity functions without any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jsp to render your page, than you have to use `<c:url>` to print the url.

**Added:**
If you can not use `<c:url>` and you need to do it by hand, then have a look at the Implmentation of `<c:url>`.

**Added:**
In JSPs you have to "wapp" `<c:url>` by `<c:out>` to get the enhanced (by session id) url correct formated.

```
<c:url var='urlWithSession' value='\myPage' />
<a href="<c:out value='${urlWithSession}'/>">my page</a>
```

Comment: The liferay theme uses .vm files which are parsed later on by liferay itself. But it doesn't seem to handle <c:url> (I tried that one). And while I certainly agree that c:url would be cleaner and httpUtil.encodeUrl, the latter should also do the trick.

Comment: One way would be implmenting the append of the session id by hand. -- But I hope for you, that you found a better solution.

Comment: Looking for one. ${} seems to get parsed. But <c:url> gets treated as plain taxt...

Comment: In jsp's you need to wrap it by <c:out>

Comment: I meant I get: 
    <a href="&lt;c:out value='${urlWithSession}'/&gt;">my page</a>